# WDIO runs both base wdio.conf file and child file rather than just the child

Tags: javascript, typescript, wdio

Thanks in advance for support here.

I am using node 16 and wdio version 8 to build a simple set of tests.  To get started on the right track I have been trying to create a base `wdio.conf.base` config file and a couple of children to inherit settings from it.

I've got the base and the child file up and running, but have noticed that when I run tests targeting the child, 2 sets of identical tests are created.  One is run against the base, and the second against the merged set.

I was suspicious that a faulty deepmerge implementation was causing duplicate entries in the configuration object, which might spawn a second set of tests, but removing all duplicate entries has eliminated that.  My current guess is that by importing `wdio.conf.base` I'm also evaluation and running it, before again merging its content into the child, and running that as well.

Any ideas on how I can get just a single test run out of this?

child file

```
import wdioConf = require('./wdio.conf')

// have main config file as default but overwrite environment specific information
export const config = deepmerge(wdioConf.config, {
    user: process.env.LT_USERNAME || "YOUR LAMBDATEST USERNAME",
    key: process.env.LT_ACCESS_KEY || "YOUR LAMBDATEST ACCESS KEY",
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: "chrome",
        browserVersion: "114.0",
        "path": "/wd/hub",
        "hostname": "hub.lambdatest.com",
        "port": 80,
        "LT:Options": {
            "platformName": "Windows 10",
            "project": "LambdaPOC",
            "build": "Implementation 1",
            "w3c": true,
            "plugin": "node_js-webdriverio",
            "tunnel": true
        }
    }],
}, { clone: false })
```

base file is effectively just the core file generated from a dummy project with a few things like baseurl corrected for my org.

Run script from package.json
`"wdio-lambda-chrome": "wdio run test/webdriver/wdio.lambda.chrome.conf.ts"`

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  My Base wdio.conf folder defined a `capabilities` block, as did the child conf file.  Rather than merging these into a single object, it ran them separately.  Removing the capabilities from the base resolved the issue.